# How to detect Blackberry mobile/playbook and Windows phone by Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, user-agent

By this article http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2011/11/detecting-mobile-devices-with-javascript/ I was successfully able to detect Iphone,Ipod,Ipad,Android device.
How can I detect Blackberry mobile/playbook and Windows phones?

Comment: why do you need to detect all these specific devices? can you not simply detect the screen size and features instead? (because otherwise you'll constantly be having to tweak your code to cope with new operating systems and version as they come out.... and this industry is moving fast enough to make that a painful thing to have to do)

Comment: Can you please elaborate more - "can you not simply detect the screen size and features instead?"

Answer (score 0):

You can detect BlackBerry devices by using:

```
navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry|BB|PlayBook/i);
```

You can detect Windows devices by using:

```
navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile|Windows Phone/i);
```

However, if you are just trying to detect if the user is on ANY mobile device, I recommend using this code:

```
if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|BB|PlayBook|IEMobile|Windows Phone|Kindle|Silk|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    // Do something for mobile users.
} else {
    // Do something for non-mobile users.
}
```